# How to debug "Call to a member function X on null" in PHP?

Tags: php, function, content-management-system, fatal-error

I am stuck on the error in my php CMS:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function send_sms() on null in /home/zleepcom/public_html/view/CartView.php on line 117

This is the code that invokes method:

```
  $this->notify->sms_send($order->phone,'Ваш заказ №'.$order->id.' принят. На сумму '.$order->total_price.' '.$this->currency->sign.'. Спасибо за заказ!');
```

this is the function:

```
    public function send_sms($r,$m)
{

public $sender='xxx';
public $slogin='xxx';
public $spwd='xxx';    
public $pdo;
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=77.120.116.10;dbname=users",$slogin,$spwd);
        $pdo->query("SET NAMES utf8;");

        $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `{$slogin}` (`number`,`message`,`sign`) VALUES ('$r','$m','$sender')");

    }catch(Exception $e){
            $client = new SoapClient ('http://turbosms.in.ua/api/wsdl.html'); 
            $auth = array( 
                'login' => $slogin, 
                'password' => $spwd 
            ); 
            $res=$client->Auth($auth);
            $sms = array( 
                'sender' => $sender, 
                'destination' => $r, 
                'text' => $m
            );
            $res=$client->SendSMS($sms); 
    }
  }
```

I would be thankful for any help

Comment: check http://turbosms.in.ua/api/wsdl.html, seems to be not working

Comment: @Chandu Is this a separate question? It's not clear what your comment has to do with this question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `$this->notify` is `null`. You haven't posted enough for us to say *why* it's `null` (it must be in your earlier code), but that's your problem.